# How to get rid of OR condition in inner join

Tags: mysql, sql, database, performance

I have a complex query which requires fields from a total of 4 tables.  I have one inner join statement which has an `OR` clause, and this is slowing the query down drastically.

This is my query:

```
   SELECT 
    pending_corrections.sightinguid AS 'pending_corrections_sightinguid',
    vehicle_ownership.id AS 'fk_vehicle_owner',
    @bill_id AS 'fk_bills',
    @nullValue AS 'fk_final_sightings_sightinguid',
    TRIM(pending_corrections.corrected_plate) AS 'vrn',
    pending_corrections.seenDate AS 'seen_date',
    cameras.in_out AS 'in_out',
    vehicle_vrn.fk_sysno AS 'fk_sysno',
    cameras.zone AS 'fk_zones',
    '0' AS 'auto_generated'
FROM
    (pending_corrections
    INNER JOIN cameras ON pending_corrections.camerauid = cameras.camera_id)
        INNER JOIN
    vehicle_vrn ON (pending_corrections.corrected_plate = vehicle_vrn.vrn500
        OR pending_corrections.corrected_plate = vehicle_vrn.vrnno)
        INNER JOIN
    vehicle_ownership ON vehicle_vrn.fk_sysno = vehicle_ownership.fk_sysno
WHERE
    pending_corrections.corrected_plate <> ''
        AND pending_corrections.corrected_plate IS NOT NULL
        AND pending_corrections.unable_to_correct <> '1'
        AND pending_corrections.seenDate >= @dateFrom
        AND pending_corrections.seenDate <= @dateTo
        AND (cameras.in_out = 1 OR cameras.in_out = 0)
        AND cameras.zone IN (SELECT 
            zone_number
        FROM
            zones
        WHERE
            fk_site = @siteId)
        AND seenDate >= vehicle_vrn.vrn_start_date
        AND (seenDate <= vehicle_vrn.vrn_end_date
        OR vehicle_vrn.vrn_end_date IS NULL
        OR vehicle_vrn.vrn_end_date = '0001-01-01 00:00:00')
        AND seenDate >= vehicle_ownership.ownership_start_date
        AND (seenDate <= vehicle_ownership.ownership_end_date
        OR vehicle_ownership.ownership_end_date IS NULL
        OR vehicle_ownership.ownership_end_date = '0001-01-01 00:00:00')
ORDER BY pending_corrections.corrected_plate , pending_corrections.seenDate ASC;
```

How can I achieve the same effect but without the `OR` in one of the joins? The reason for the `OR` clause is because the `pending_corrections.corrected_plate` value has to match either the `vrn500` or `vrnno` columns in the `vehicle_vrn` table.

Comment: It is a duplicate of your last question and then you change it after answers are posted.  Come on man.

Comment: Not really @Frisbee - this question is more specific as it deals with the OR section of the inner join only, rather than the whole query itself.

Comment: From the duplicate "How can I achieve the same effect but without the OR in one of the joins?"

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using two equals expressions with an OR, you could use a IN expression such as:

```
FROM
    (pending_corrections
    INNER JOIN cameras ON pending_corrections.camerauid = cameras.camera_id)
        INNER JOIN 
    vehicle_vrn ON pending_corrections.corrected_plate IN(vehicle_vrn.vrn500, vehicle_vrn.vrnno)
        INNER JOIN
    vehicle_ownership ON vehicle_vrn.fk_sysno = vehicle_ownership.fk_sysno
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but when I ran the EXPLAIN statement it seems to result in two full table scans anyway.

Answer (score 0):

What's the execution plan look like? SQL probably can't optimize this join into a hash or merge, so is just having to do table scans.

Sometimes with ORs, a UNION works well. It's more code but can run faster because SQL can optimize them better.

```
; WITH PendingCorrectionsCte AS
(
    SELECT  pc.corrected_plate,
            pc.seen_date,
            c.in_out,
            pc.sightinguid AS 'pending_corrections_sightinguid',
    FROM    pending_corrections pc
            INNER JOIN cameras c ON pending_corrections.camerauid = cameras.camera_id
    WHERE   pc.seenDate BETWEEN '2015-01-01 00:00:00' AND '2015-01-31 23:59:59'
            AND NULLIF(LTRIM(pc.corrected_plate), '') IS NOT NULL
            AND pending_corrections.unable_to_correct <> '1'
            AND pending_corrections.seenDate >= @dateFrom
            AND pending_corrections.seenDate <= @dateTo
            AND c.in_out IN (0, 1)
            AND c.zone IN (SELECT zone_number FROM zones WHERE fk_site = @siteId)
),
VrnCte AS
(
    SELECT  pc.corrected_plate,
            pc.seen_date,
            vrn.fk_sysno,
            pc.in_out,
            pc.pending_corrections_sightinguid
    FROM    PendingCorrectionsCte pc
            INNER JOIN vehicle_vrn vrn ON pc.corrected_plate = vehicle_vrn.vrn500
            -- Could also do this inline in the where clause, but chaining isnull and nullif could get hard to read
            CROSS APPLY (SELECT NULLIF(vrn.vrn_end_date, '0001-01-01 00:00:00') AS value) vrn_end_date
    WHERE   pc.seenDate BETWEEN vrn.vrn_start_date AND ISNULL(vrn_end_date.value, seenDate)

    UNION

    SELECT  pc.corrected_plate,
            pc.seenDate,
            vrn.fk_sysno,
            pc.in_out,
            pc.pending_corrections_sightinguid
    FROM    pending_corrections pc
            INNER JOIN vehicle_vrn vrn ON pc.corrected_plate = vehicle_vrn.vrnno
            -- Could also do this inline in the where clause, but chaining isnull and nullif could get hard to read
            CROSS APPLY (SELECT NULLIF(vrn.vrn_end_date, '0001-01-01 00:00:00') AS value) vrn_end_date
    WHERE   pc.seenDate BETWEEN vrn.vrn_start_date AND ISNULL(vrn_end_date.value, seenDate)
)
SELECT  pending_corrections.sightinguid AS 'pending_corrections_sightinguid',
        vo.id AS 'fk_vehicle_owner',
        @bill_id AS 'fk_bills',
        @nullValue AS 'fk_final_sightings_sightinguid',
        TRIM(VrnCte.corrected_plate) AS 'vrn',
        VrnCte.seenDate AS 'seen_date',
        VrnCte.in_out AS 'in_out',
        VrnCte.fk_sysno AS 'fk_sysno',
        VrnCte.pending_corrections_sightinguid
        '0' AS 'auto_generated'
FROM    VrnCte 
        INNER JOIN vehicle_ownership vo ON VrnCte.fk_sysno = vo.fk_sysno
        CROSS APPLY (SELECT NULLIF(vo.ownership_end_date, '0001-01-01 00:00:00') AS value) ownership_end_date
WHERE   VrnCte.seenDate BETWEEN vehicle_ownership.ownership_start_date AND ISNULL(ownership_end_date.value, seenDate)
ORDER BY 
        VrnCte.corrected_plate, 
        VrnCte.seenDate ASC
```

Comment: I edited the question to contain the full query.

Comment: Ok, edited to show a possible way to do this by chaining CTEs to make the pending_corrections filters easier to maintain for the UNION.

Comment: What is the first part which says "WITH"?

Comment: MySQL has not implemented CTEs.

Comment: Damn, sorry, missed that you tagged it mysql. Guess you'd have to go with a temp table or subquery to use this approach.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the first `OR` using `IN()`, as Scott mentioned

```
pending_corrections.corrected_plate IN (vehicle_vrn.vrn500, vehicle_vrn.vrnno)
```

If you can `UPDATE` the `vrn_end_date` and `ownership_end_date` columns from `'0001-01-01 00:00:00'` to `NULL`, the other `OR` conditions can be simplified to

```
AND (seenDate <= IFNULL(vehicle_vrn.vrn_end_date, seenDate))
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but when I ran the EXPLAIN statement it seems to result in two full table scans anyway.

Comment: Performance may be worse but it does get rid of the `OR` ;)

Comment: Correct but unfortunately the performance seems to be the same or worse. I should have clarified, but the reason for wanting to get rid of the OR is for performance :)